# slack update modal view on on_enter_pressed

Tags: slack, modal-view

I'm trying to update the `hint` of an input text on my modal view upon the user press enter.

Slack documentation state that it is possible using `on_enter_pressed` but I can't get it to work.

This is the code that get properly called on the action `on_enter_pressed` but it throw an error

```
private com.slack.api.bolt.response.Response checkFileAlreadyInRepo(BlockActionRequest request, ActionContext actionContext)
    throws IOException {
    Assert.notNull(request, "block action request");
    
    request.getPayload().getView().getBlocks().forEach(b -> {
        if(b.getBlockId().equals("file-url-block")){
            ((InputBlock) b).setHint(PlainTextObject.builder().text("hello").build());
        }
    });

    actionContext.respond(b -> b
        .replaceOriginal(true).blocks(request.getPayload().getView().getBlocks())
    );

    return actionContext.ack();
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method okhttp3.Request$Builder.url, parameter url
at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.kt) ~[okhttp-4.9.2.jar:na]
at com.slack.api.util.http.SlackHttpClient.postJsonBody(SlackHttpClient.java:184) ~[slack-api-client-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.app_backend.interactive_components.ActionResponseSender.send(ActionResponseSender.java:21) ~[slack-app-backend-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.util.Responder.send(Responder.java:52) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.context.ActionRespondUtility.respond(ActionRespondUtility.java:31) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.context.ActionRespondUtility.respond(ActionRespondUtility.java:36) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.workday.be.throg.service.upload_file.UploadFileService.checkFileAlreadyInRepo(UploadFileService.java:158) ~[main/:na]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.runHandler(App.java:1147) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.lambda$runMiddleware$3(App.java:1003) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.middleware.builtin.IgnoringSelfEvents.apply(IgnoringSelfEvents.java:97) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.runMiddleware(App.java:1003) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.lambda$runMiddleware$4(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.middleware.builtin.SingleTeamAuthorization.apply(SingleTeamAuthorization.java:87) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.runMiddleware(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.lambda$runMiddleware$4(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.middleware.builtin.RequestVerification.apply(RequestVerification.java:27) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.runMiddleware(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.lambda$runMiddleware$4(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.middleware.builtin.SSLCheck.apply(SSLCheck.java:51) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.runMiddleware(App.java:1006) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.App.run(App.java:575) ~[bolt-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.bolt.socket_mode.SocketModeApp.lambda$buildSocketModeClient$0(SocketModeApp.java:37) ~[bolt-socket-mode-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.socket_mode.SocketModeClient.processMessage(SocketModeClient.java:355) ~[slack-api-client-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at com.slack.api.socket_mode.SocketModeClient.lambda$initializeMessageProcessorExecutor$0(SocketModeClient.java:157) ~[slack-api-client-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_345]
```

Not sure why `responseUrl` is null, I was expecting to be populated in the `ActionContext`

message:
[image]

Modal view:
[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution? Please just comment for more info thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a chat with Slack support team, at present is not possible to dynamically change the modal view, they said it could be a future feature, no date yet.